# How to save __evalVar function value into a variable and re-use it for comparison

Tags: jmeter

We have scenario where two variables are extracted from two samplers, and these variables needs to be compared. For this, have created two samplers with each one having 1 regex with matchno: -1, and used ForEach controller>under it 'counter' been used where i have used function ${__evalVar(test_${test_all})}

For this, need to store this ${__evalVar(test_${test_all})} value to a variable so that can be re-used in other places to compare.

Is storing a value from the __evalVar function possible and how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) which can evaluate your expression and store the value into a variable of your choice, i.e. `varFromJexl3`:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${__evalVar(test_${test_all})}",varFromJexl3)}
   ```
2. You can consider switching to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which is probably [the most powerful and flexible JMeter Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) I can think of. The relevant syntax to evaluate `test_${test_all}` variable and store it into `varFromGroovy` variable would be something like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('test_' + vars.get('test_all')), varFromGroovy)}
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]